# MFC - Correct place and order of object deletion

Tags: mfc

I have a `CDialog`, containing members such as

```
CButton *p1;
CEdit *p2;
```

.....

All of which call `::create` at `OnInitDialog`.

It seems like I don't free memory correctly after I am done with the dialog.

Can anyone refer me to a good document/link about best practice to free up memory for MFC Windows Objects?

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: Why do you use pointers, simply use the objects CButton b1; etc.

Comment: Is it important?  My question is still the same if I use objects. If m_button falls out of scope, its destructor is called, and the same happens if I call delete m_pButton.  But where should I call DestroyWindow, etc.?

Comment: RAII. It's the magic that frees up your mind to get things done. You don't ever need pointers to control objects, unless they are optional one way or another, or if their lifetime doesn't coincide with their parents'. For a dialog neither one is likely to be the case. Just use composition, and you don't have to worry about anything. Except, since you were asking about `DestroyWindow`, you really, **really** need to learn, how MFC manages resources of a flat C API in a C++ class system.

Comment: And what's a good link for that ?

Comment: To be honest, we would need to see the complete code of your dialog class. We can't really see what is going on from what has been provided. If you use the ClassWizard correctly the variables associated with each control should be created and managed on your behalf. Usually you use pointers where you are getting the control from the dialog item ID. But you can also map the control to a member variable rather than a pointer. For example, a `EDIT` control can be mapped to a variable (eg: `CString`) and a `Control` (eg: `CEdit`).